# How do you draw a DFA from a regular expression?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I want to draw a DFA from the below language:

> The set of strings in $\{a, b\}$ where every $a$ is immediately followed by $b$

I can write the regular expression for this language as so:

$$((b^*)(ab)(b^*))^*$$

How do I draw the DFA for this expression?

Comment: In general, the procedure is to draw a non-deterministic finite automaton from the regular expression, then convert to a DFA (where the states consist of set of states of the NDFA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it can help you

Language consist of :

- $\epsilon$
- strings of just b's
- and strings such that every **a** is immediately followed by **b**
  $$L=\{\epsilon,b,bb,bbb,...,ab,abb,....,bab,bbababb,.... \}$$
  Regular expression: $(b^*\,ab\, b^*)^*+b^*$

DFA that accepts L :

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Just out of curiosity: what software did you use to draw the diagram?

Comment: Thanks @zipirovich :) I used FSM Designer (http://madebyevan.com/fsm/) Created by Evan Wallace

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on-line using https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/nfa2dfa easily.
For your particular example, [it gives](https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/nfa2dfa?regex=KChiKikoYWIpKGIqKSkq)

[image]

You can find a more precise algorithm in the chapter 2 of [Modern Compiler Implementation in C](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/modern/c/), which includes this figure:

[image]

How you convert your obtained NFA into a DFA is then [fairly standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).

Comment: Underrated answer